# Fgets does not seem to be invoked

Tags: c

So I have this code where I use fgets(), to read in a big string. But my program seems to just jump over that and not use it at all. What might be the reason?

```
char temp[50], question[50], temp3[50];
printf("What animal did you mean?");
fgets(temp, 50, stdin);
printf("How would you ask if %s is different from %s\n", PrintCont(abi), temp);
fgets(question, 50, stdin);
printf("And if you say yes to that question, is it %s then?[y/n]", temp);
printf("|%s|\n", question);
if(YesNo() != 'y'){
```

So it prints everything out that there is, skips the fgets() and then goes for the if statement which invokes function YesNo() , which asks for input with scanf().

YesNO function:

```
char YesNo(void){
   char answer = ' ';
   while (answer != 'y' && answer != 'n') {
       scanf(" %c",&answer);
       fflush(stdin);
   }
   return answer;
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this works if I run it in Windows with Dev C++, but not on Linux with gcc.

Comment: Undefined behaviour: `fflush(stdin);` Post definition of `PrintCont()`.

Comment: Check return value of `scanf` (read docs to see what it means).

Comment: Well I figured that something might have been left in my stdin so I used fflush() to clear it.

Comment: Also, as a general hint, do not mix `scanf` and `fgets`, it's hard to get right. Use `fgets` to get line, then use `sscanf` to parse values out of that, if you need both.

Comment: It was not originally in my code, it's just that after the fgets() did not work for me,  I started to flush stdin everywhere to see if something was left in

Comment: As a side note, many animal names have spaces in them...

Comment: I also added my YesNo() function to original post. Worth to mention that I cannot use fgets() in that function, it will give me a error.

Comment: @Veske Please look up the meaning of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). A statement such as "I started to flush stdin everywhere to see if something was left in" simply *makes no sense*, since you *cannot* flush `stdin`. It compiled, sure, but you cannot run that code and get any kind of sensible result. It is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: What is the contents of `question` before that `if` statement? You could print out that by adding something like `printf("|%s|\n", question);` before your `if` statement. By the way, you should define `question` as `char question[50] = {0};` to give elements of it a determinate value.

Comment: The `fflush` function is only for flushing output streams.

Comment: @leeduhem,  I changed the question where it asks for animal too to fgets not.  The behaviour is now that it skips the first fgets() and then the second fgets() gets executed right. So I am guessin the fault is in my YesNo() function which is using scanf() and fflush right?

Comment: @unwind It looks like `fflush(stdin);` has a determinate behavior on Linux, check [its man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) out.

Comment: @Veske There is only one `fgets()` call in your code, and I do not believe it will be skipped.

Comment: Edited original code. This is how it looks like now, It skips first fgets() and goes for second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous other potential problems with the code, but to fix the issue you ask about, this should do it: replace `fflush(stdin)` with this:

```
int ch;
do {
    ch = getchar();
} while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

that will read from stdin until end-of-line or end-of-file/error.

Ideally, wrap that code in a function and call that.

Comment: This code is broken, `getchar()` returns `int`, since `EOF` is not a character. Please fix.

Comment: @unwind ah yes, thanks! This also demonstrates, how easy it is to make this particular, common mistake with `getchar()` & co...

Answer (score 0):

```
 fflush(stdin);
```

doesnt work. use

```
 getchar();
```

To clear the input buffer by removing the leftover `newline` character

Answer (score 0):

How about getline and read functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char YesNo(void)
{
        char answer = ' ';
        do {
           if (read(fileno(stdin), &answer, sizeof answer) != sizeof answer)
                continue;
           answer = tolower (answer);
        } while ((answer != 'y') && (answer != 'n'));
        return answer;
}
int main ()
{
        char *temp = NULL, *question = NULL, temp3[50];
        size_t n = 0, rval = 0;
        printf("What animal did you mean? ");
        rval = getline(&temp, &n, stdin);
        temp[rval-1] = '\0';
        printf("How would you ask if %s is different from %s ? ","test", temp);
        rval = getline(&question, &n, stdin);
        question[rval-1] = '\0';
        printf("And if you say yes to that question, is it %s then ?[y/n]", temp);
        fflush (stdout);
        if (YesNo () == 'y')
                printf ("YES");
}
```

Note: Do not forget to check return values.